# python - iterate over various imports

Tags: python, variables, import, iteration

If I do something like

```
import my_import
from my_import import *
```

I can change variables in the import by doing something like

```
my_import.k = 6
```

If I wanted to change the value of k for every single import I used, is there a way for me to iterate over all imports and set the value of k in each?

Essentially I'm looking for something like

```
for each x in [list of imports]
    x.k = 6
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm attempting to automate grading for students' assignments. There will be roughly 90 files with unpredictable names, and each of the files is presumed to have a variable named "k" at the top of the file. While I need only import one of these files at a time, I felt it was more likely that there would be functionality to iterate over all imports, rather than somehow using a single variable or something to switch out the names of import modules. It's possible I'm wrong, though, in which case I'd be interested to hear how that would be done.

Comment: It would be wiser to structure the assignments such that you don't have to inject a variable like this - why not e.g. make it an argument to some `main` entry-point function?

Comment: @jonrsharpe While I realize this, I am not the one who makes the assignments, I am just the grader. The students were instructed to set k to a certain value, but were also told to make it easily changeable at the top of the file, so we need to check that their functions work with different values of k (preferably without manually changing each one).

Comment: @jonrsharpe It was the creators of the textbook/lab exercises at Harvey Mudd: https://www.cs.hmc.edu/twiki/bin/view/ModularCS1/ImageCompression!

The only extra instructions given to the student was to make k changeable, and if they follow the specifications provided in the lab, it is likely that they'll set k outside of the functions they write - if they followed the lab directly, they'd probably just hardcode the number "5" into their submission. Intro to CS students. :P

Answer (score 2):

There's some reasons to want this, but it's a dangerous game.

```
import my_import1
import my_import2
import my_import3
import sys

# Check if you don't believe me
print(my_import1.x)
print(my_import2.x)
print(my_import3.x)

# Grab the interesection of all loaded modules and globals in this scope
allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in set(sys.modules)&set(globals())]

for module in allmodules:
    module.x = 10000

# Check if you don't believe me
print(my_import1.x)
print(my_import2.x)
print(my_import3.x)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
10000
10000
10000
```

The caveat with this is that it will grab 'sys' as well and alter it. Perhaps add a check for "built-in" in the module key name.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanna change the attribute value of the imported module objects, you may try this code using function `__import__()` and `map()`:

```
#__import__() & map()

In [1]: moduleNames = ['my_import1', 'my_import2', 'my_import3']

In [2]: for module in map(__import__, moduleNames):
   ...:     module.k = 1000
   ...:
```

And you can check the result by import this modules one by one, and output the k:

```
In [3]: import my_import1, my_import2, my_import3

In [4]: print my_import1.k
1000

In [5]: print my_import2.k
1000

In [6]: print my_import3.k
1000
```

Actually, you can change the map() function into a **List Comprehension** or a **Generator**, **and the code would be much resemble your demanding code-style**:

```
#List Comprehension

In [7]: for module in [__import__(m) for m in moduleNames]:
   ...:     module.k = 2000
   ...:     

In [8]: print my_import1.k
2000

In [9]: print my_import2.k
2000

In [10]: print my_import3.k
2000

In [11]: 

#Generator

In [11]: for module in (__import__(m) for m in moduleNames):
   ....:     module.k = 3000
   ....:     

In [12]: print my_import1.k
3000

In [13]: print my_import2.k
3000

In [14]: print my_import3.k
3000

In [15]:
```

BTW, the list comprehension and generator are quite similar, though. **Generator is much more recommended when you have a large number of modules to deal with and no need to import them all at one time**. It's more efficient and memory-saving.